# Automaticly send email after Paypal transaction

Tags: paypal

I need help on making a digital delivery system for my website.

- Buyer clicks a paypal buy now button
- Buyer completes paypal transaction
- Buyer is redirected to a page on my website, and an email is sent to their paypal email address from me.

How should I go about doing this any info would be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for PayPal's **Instant Payment Notification**.

> Instant Payment Notification consists of three parts:
>
> 1. Someone pays you.
> 2. PayPal POSTs FORM variables to a URL you specify
>      that runs a program to process the variables.
> 3. You validate the
>      notification.

The above is quoted from PayPal's [HTML Form Basics for Website Payments Standard](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics). Obviously, step 3 is where you will send an email to your customer.

To learn more about IPN, here is an in-depth explanation of PayPal's [IPN Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf).
To learn more about the *Buy Now* buttons, check out [Single-Item Payments - Buy Now Buttons](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_buynow_buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use this in your afterPaypalNotification callback in your AppController.php

```
function afterPaypalNotification($txnId)
{
ClassRegistry::init('PaypalIpn.InstantPaymentNotification')->email(array('id' => $txnId,
    'subject' => 'Thanks!',
    'message' => 'Thank you for the transaction!'
));  
}
```